# Mongodb sort inner array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've been looking for a while now and can't seem to sort an inner array and keep that in the doc that I'm currently working with.

```js
{
    "service": {
        "apps": {
            "updates": [
              {
                "n" : 1
                "date": ISODate("2012-03-10T16:15:00Z")
              },
              {
                "n" : 2
                "date": ISODate("2012-01-10T16:15:00Z")
              },
              {
                "n" : 5
                "date": ISODate("2012-07-10T16:15:00Z")
              }
            ]
        }
     }
 }
```

So I want to keep the item to be returned as the service, but have my updates array sorted. So far with the shell I have:

```js
db.servers.aggregate(
        {$unwind:'$service'},
        {$project:{'service.apps':1}},
        {$unwind:'$service.apps'}, 
        {$project: {'service.apps.updates':1}}, 
        {$sort:{'service.apps.updates.date':1}});
```

Anyone think they can help on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort nested array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432727/sort-nested-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can do this by `$unwind`ing the `updates` array, sorting the resulting docs by `date`, and then `$group`ing them back together on `_id` using the sorted order.

```js
db.servers.aggregate(
    {$unwind: '$service.apps.updates'}, 
    {$sort: {'service.apps.updates.date': 1}}, 
    {$group: {_id: '$_id', 'updates': {$push: '$service.apps.updates'}}}, 
    {$project: {'service.apps.updates': '$updates'}})
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm pretty new to aggregation and had a feeling it could do something like this.

Comment: what about if apps had a field like "name" and I wanted to keep the name in the result set as well?

Comment: @user1251624 You would include that field in the `$group` (in the `_id` or as a separate field) and `$project`.  If you need more help on that it's probably best to ask that as a separate question as it can be non-trivial.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Is the order of `group`ing after `sort` always guaranteed?

Comment: @RaR For `$push` yes, AFAIK. For `$addToSet` no, unfortunately.

Comment: What if "apps" was also an array? I have this problem. It returned 0 results

Comment: It is sorting the full set the documents before grouping, not efficient if you have so much data

Answer (score 17):

Starting in `Mongo 4.4`, the [`$function`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html) aggregation operator allows applying a custom javascript function to implement behaviour not supported by the MongoDB Query Language.

For instance, in order to sort an array of objects by one of their fields:

```
// {
//   "service" : { "apps" : { "updates" : [
//     { "n" : 1, "date" : ISODate("2012-03-10T16:15:00Z") },
//     { "n" : 2, "date" : ISODate("2012-01-10T16:15:00Z") },
//     { "n" : 5, "date" : ISODate("2012-07-10T16:15:00Z") }
//   ]}}
// }
db.collection.aggregate(
  { $set: {
    { "service.apps.updates":
      { $function: {
          body: function(updates) {
            updates.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);
            return updates;
          },
          args: ["$service.apps.updates"],
          lang: "js"
      }}
    }
  }
)
// {
//   "service" : { "apps" : { "updates" : [
//     { "n" : 2, "date" : ISODate("2012-01-10T16:15:00Z") },
//     { "n" : 1, "date" : ISODate("2012-03-10T16:15:00Z") },
//     { "n" : 5, "date" : ISODate("2012-07-10T16:15:00Z") }
//   ]}}
// }
```

---

This modifies the array in place, without having to apply a combination of expensive `$unwind`, `$sort` and `$group` stages.

`$function` takes 3 parameters:

- `body`, which is the function to apply, whose parameter is the array to modify.
- `args`, which contains the fields from the record that the `body` function takes as parameter. In our case `"$service.apps.updates"`.
- `lang`, which is the language in which the `body` function is written. Only `js` is currently available.

Comment: For Atlas users, `$function` is not available in free tier (as of May 2021)

Answer (score 13):

Starting in `Mongo 5.2`, it's the exact use case for the new [`$sortArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/#mongodb-expression-exp.-sortArray) aggregation operator:

```
// {
//   service: { apps: { updates: [
//     { n: 1, date: ISODate("2012-03-10") },
//     { n: 2, date: ISODate("2012-01-10") },
//     { n: 5, date: ISODate("2012-07-10") }
//   ]}}
// }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $set: {
    "service.apps.updates": {
      $sortArray: {
        input: "$service.apps.updates",
        sortBy: { date: 1 }
      }
    }
  }}
])
// {
//   service: { apps: { updates: [
//     { n: 2, date: ISODate("2012-01-10") },
//     { n: 1, date: ISODate("2012-03-10") },
//     { n: 5, date: ISODate("2012-07-10") }
//   ]}}
// }
```

---

This:

- sorts (`$sortArray`) the `service.apps.updates` array (`input: "$service.apps.updates"`)
- by applying a sort on `date`s (`sortBy: { date: 1 }`)
- without having to apply a combination of expensive `$unwind`, `$sort` and `$group` stages

Answer (score 0):

```
 const timelines = await Timeline.aggregate<TimelineDoc>([
    {
      $match: {
        $and: query,
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: '$badges',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    { $sort: { 'badges.updatedAt': MongoSortOrder.Descending } },
    {
      $group: {
    _id: '$_id',
    badges: {
      $addToSet: {
        name: '$badges.name',
        thumbnail: '$badges.thumbnail',
        updatedAt: '$badges.updatedAt',
        user: '$badges.user',
      },
    },
    createdAt: { $first: '$createdAt' },
  },
    },
    { $sort: sort },
    { $skip: skip },
    { $limit: limit },
  ]);
```