# MongoDB Query Nested Array Search

Tags: mongodb, database

I need to query documents with mongoDb that contain nested arrays.  I see a lot of examples using the simple $in operator.  The only problem is that I strictly need to check for proper subsets.

Consider the following document.

```
{data: [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]}
```

The query needs to be able to get documents with all of [1,2,3] where 1,2,3 can be in any order, which rules out the following query, because it will only match in the correct order.

```
{data:{$elemMatch:{$all:[[1,2,3]]}}}
```

I've also tried nested $elemMatch operators with no success, because the $in operator will return the document even if only one element matches such as the following.

```
 {data:{$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{$in:[1,4]}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your actual query looks like, but this should do what you need:
db.documentDto.find({"some_field":{"$elemMatch":{"$in":[1,2,3]}} })

Comment: Please go back and carefully re-read my question.  Especially, where I explicitly state "The only problem is that I strictly need to check for proper subsets. ".

Comment: Ok for "subset" portion of your question, have you looked at "setIsSubset"? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got a complete answer (and not much time as its late here) but I would consider

1. Using aggregation pipeline instead of a query if your not already
2. Use $unwind operator to deconstruct your nested arrays
3. Use $sort to sort the contents of the arrays - so you can now compare
4. Use $match to filter out the arrays which don't fit the array subset values as you can now check based on order.
5. Use $group to group the result back together based on the _id value

Ref: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/ will give you info on each of the above.

From a quick search I came up with a similar question/example that might be helpful: [Mongodb sort inner array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388127/mongodb-sort-inner-array)

Comment: I'd rather not, being the find function that is being used converts the query into an aggregation.  The unit test is only testing the insertion of the document so I might just go ahead and use an aggregation instead.  I'll think about it, and wait to see if there is a possible solution using queries.

Comment: I couldn't see a way to do it with a find() which is why I suggested aggregation. I believe using the outline above you should be able to achieve what you are looking to do.