# MongoDb: aggregation $lookup with filtering over the foreign documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given a couple of collecitons:

1.- USERS

```
{
  name: ...
  id: ...
  city: ...
  age: ...
  otherdata: ...
}
```

2.- PETS

```
{
  name: ...
  owner: ...
  type: ...
  age: ...
}
```

I'm trying to use aggregation with $lookup to build a set of objects that represent users with their pets:

```
collectionusers.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup: {
       from: "pets",
       localField: "id",
       foreignField: "owner",
       as: "pets"
     }
   }
]);
```

But I'd like to add a filter so that only pets older than 1 year are added to each user (using field age inside the pet objects).

The problem is, adding $match in the aggregation does not work because it filters out users without old pets, and I want the users to be there even if they don't have pets.

Actually I'm also trying to get only the oldest of the pets of each user in the same way and I also didn't find the formula.

Any way to perform this action within the aggregation?

Of course, currently I'm doing it afterwards, on the returned objects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) array aggregation operator on `pets` array that is produced by your `$lookup` stage.

To output pets older than 1 year use

```
db.users.aggregate([ 
{ 
  $lookup: 
  { 
    from: "pets", 
    localField: "id", 
    foreignField: "owner", 
    as: "pets" 
  } 
}, 
{
  $project: 
  {
    name: 1,
    pets: 
    { 
      $filter: 
      { 
        input: "$pets", 
        as: "pet", 
        cond: { $gte: [ "$$pet.age", 1 ] } 
      } 
    } 
  } 
} 
]);
```

To output the oldest pets simply replace `cond` field of `$filter` operator in the previous aggregation pipeline with

```
cond: { $eq: [ "$$pet.age", { $max: "$pets.age" } ] }
```

Comment: Great, thanks. 

One more think I'm going to look into myself, but just in case you're faster: what if I just want to limit the number of pets in the "pets" array?

:-)

Comment: Look at [**`$slice`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/#exp._S_slice) operator and use it in `$project` stage instead of `$filter`.

Comment: Yes, I'm fighting with $slice, but I need some sorting before slicing... I want to slice the right ones :-)

Comment: To be clear, the actual query I'm looking for would be everything at once, but I decided to ask step by step and try each step by myself:

- There's a condition over the age of the pet ($gte 1)
- There's a max number of pets per user ($slice -3), the 3 oldest.
- There are 3 types of pet and I have to split the pet array in 3 arrays by type, but that I'm sure I'll have to post-process :-)

Thanks for the guidance :-)

Comment: Try to add one more `$project` stage with `$slice` operator after `$project` stage with `$filter` operator.

Comment: I still need to sort. The filter gives me the $gte 1 and the slice gives me a number of them, but no the oldest among them :-)

I don't see how to pre-sort.

Comment: After `$filter` stage use [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [**`$sort`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/), [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) like showed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388127/mongodb-sort-inner-array), and then perform `$slice`.