# Can I sort the values in a field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

If I have a document like this

```
{'id': 123, 'keywords': {'keyword1': 3, 'keyword2': 8, 'keyword3': 2}}
```

Can I get a query result with keywords sorted by values, like

```
{'id': 123, 'keywords': {'keyword3': 2, 'keyword1': 3, 'keyword2': 8}}
```

Is there a built-in mongodb feature for doing this? Or I have to implement this in application level?

Comment: I don't see a way to do with the dynamic fields you've. You can use aggregate if you were to change `keywords` to `[{'keyword': 3}, {'keyword': 8}, {'keyword': 2}]` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388127/mongodb-sort-inner-array

Comment: Field order is rarely important; why do you want to do this?

Comment: Hi @JohnnyHK, the goal is to find out top/bottom Kth keywords.

Comment: @Kyle Then you should probably use an array like Veeram suggests, but with objects in the array like `{keyword: 'keyword1', value: 3}`.

Comment: that's a good idea. I will give it a try. thanks!

Comment: You can take a look at answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558778/how-to-retrieve-distinct-keys-inside-an-object-in-mongodb/43559471#43559471 which makes use of new aggregation operator `$objectToArray` from 3.4.4 to convert from object from array without the need to update the data in the collection and then use the answer I mentioned in my previous comment for sorting. Only downside you can't use index if you don't update the collection.