# nodejs+moongose sort inner array by element timestamp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I have the follwing schema:

```
  var VisionsystemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  linenumber: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    unique: true
  },
  name: String,
  rois: [
    {
      name: String,
      history: [Date, Number]
    }
  ]
});
```

for each element in rois array i have an array of history values with a [date,number] tuple. how can i order the history array by its Date first element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb sort inner array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388127/mongodb-sort-inner-array)

Comment: the question veeram mentions includes sorting inner array

Comment: Is first element date max or min date or some random date ?

Comment: @Veeram is a random date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below aggregation query.

`$unwind` the `rois` array followed by sorting the docs by first element and `$group` back on `_id` to get the sorted array.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$rois"},
  {"$sort":{"rois.history.0":-1}},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$_id","rois":{"$push":"$rois.history"}}}
])
```