# How to return all fields without specify after $group stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to sort the child array in a document and keep the parent fields? 
I have a collection like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1757929831633ff8abb638"), 
    "name" : "Carraro Exlusive", 
    "description" : "Carraro Exlusive description", 
    "image" : "image-15", 
    "__v" : 0, 
    "sellers" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1757929831633ff8abb639"), 
            "product" : ObjectId("5d1757929831633ff8abb638"), 
            "seller" : ObjectId("5d1518582f9254189ca92e59"), 
            "price" : 13, 
            "stock" : 5, 
            "__v" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d175b60cf85a22f745235ee"), 
            "product" : ObjectId("5d1757929831633ff8abb638"), 
            "seller" : ObjectId("5d164802c4dc7811b0f34b86"), 
            "price" : 10, 
            "stock" : 222, 
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want to sort the inner sellers array by price from smallest to largest.

The result I want is:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1757929831633ff8abb638"), 
    "name" : "Carraro Exlusive", 
    "description" : "Carraro Exlusive", 
    "category" : ObjectId("5d151ad1b72c830f14374bb4"), 
    "brand" : ObjectId("5d151981b72c830f14374bb2"), 
    "image" : "image-15", 
    "__v" : 0, 
    "sellers" : [
     {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d175b60cf85a22f745235ee"), 
            "product" : ObjectId("5d1757929831633ff8abb638"), 
            "seller" : ObjectId("5d164802c4dc7811b0f34b86"), 
            "price" : 10, 
            "stock" : 222, 
            "__v" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1757929831633ff8abb639"), 
            "product" : ObjectId("5d1757929831633ff8abb638"), 
            "seller" : ObjectId("5d1518582f9254189ca92e59"), 
            "price" : 13, 
            "stock" : 5, 
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I saw the following post, but I want to keep the parent fields:
[Mongodb sort inner array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388127/mongodb-sort-inner-array)

Comment: @Ashh as I indicated in the post, I already saw the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388127/mongodb-sort-inner-array
What I want is to keep the parent fields.

Comment: Yes, I saw. You just need to use `$first` accumulator in the group stage.

Comment: @Ashh  doesn't $first get the first item in the array, what I want to do is sort the array by price. If I didn't understand what you said, could you please tell me what the group stage should look like?

Comment: @Ashh thank you, but I didn't want to specify all parent fields in the group stage,
what if the document contained 20-30 parent fields?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/6OyQ8k_96X-

Comment: @Ashh great:) thank you very much, is there a way to accept this as an answer?

Comment: @Ashh you should put that query in the answer. This solution will show up in google search for similar questions. I can copy paste your query in the answer sometime soon if you did not get the chance to do so.. pretty cool +1

Comment: @JBone yeah!!! Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$sellers" },
  { "$sort": { "sellers.price": 1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "sellers": { "$push": "$sellers" },
    "allFields": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        "$allFields",
        { "sellers": "$sellers" }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```