# Sorting array inside array in Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, pymongo

db.information is the collection that contains the following structure:

```
information:
           {
               class_num:
                { 
                     standard:
                     [
                           {
                             name:tom,
                             weight:30
                           },
                           {
                             name:mike,
                             weight:32
                           },
                           {
                             name:sally,
                             weight:25
                           }
                      ]
                }
            }
```

I want to sort this data by weight, I tried to use `find().sort('weight':-1)` but it doesn't work. How should I point the sort towards the array inside array?

Comment: like this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388127/mongodb-sort-inner-array

Comment: use: information.class_num.standard.$.1.weight

Comment: @jinzy I tried it with just one change, adding  {'$match':{ '_id' : ObjectId("5d69c4d11c9d440000792682")}}, as first line along with the other lines mentioned db.servers.aggregate(
    {$unwind: '$service.apps.updates'}, 
    {$sort: {'service.apps.updates.date': 1}}, 
    {$group: {_id: '$_id', 'updates': {$push: '$service.apps.updates'}}}, 
    {$project: {'service.apps.updates': '$updates'}}), but i am getting an error,  The field '5d69c4d11c9d440000792682' must be an accumulator object
I am not sure how to proceed