# MongoDb sorting documents with multiple nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

There is a document with nested arrays, just want to sort collection by *customerId*  then *productList.productId* and then *productList.itemList.id* in ascending order. MongoDb version is 3.0.14.

I've tried so far this and the query doesn't sort the collection as expected:

```
db.file_old.find({}, {
        customerId: 1,
        "productList.productId": 1,
        "productList.itemList.id": 1
    })
    .sort({
        customerId: 1,
        productList: 1,
        "productList.itemList": 1
    })
```

and try aggregate framework also like this:

```
db.file_old.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$productList"} ,
    {"$sort": {"customerId": 1, "productList.productId": 1}}
])
```

It work fine for two field but if try to adding "productList.itemList.id" doesn't work, like this:

```
db.file_old.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$productList"} ,
    {"$sort": {"customerId": 1, "productList.productId": 1,  "productList.itemList.id": 1}}
])
```

Collection structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f33cc2a1e84082968132324"),
    "customerId" : 2196,
    "productList" : [
        {
            "productId" : 7531,
            "itemList" : [
                {
                    "id" : 144
                },
                {
                    "id" : 145
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "productId" : 7534,
            "itemList" : [
                {
                    "id" : 1244
                },
                {
                    "id" : 1243
                },
                {
                    "id" : 1245
                },
                {
                    "id" : 1242
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f33cc2a1e84082968132326"),
    "customerId" : 2201,
    "productList" : [
        {
            "productId" : 101201,
            "itemList" : [
                {
                    "id" : 863
                },
                {
                    "id" : 865
                },
                {
                    "id" : 862
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "productId" : 7537,
            "itemList" : [
                {
                    "id" : 982
                },
                {
                    "id" : 1002
                },
                {
                    "id" : 896
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not sort directly array, first requires to unwind(deconstruct) and then sort will apply, lets see step by step,

> - **productList**
> - deconstruct array ($unwind)
>
> > - **itemList**
> > - deconstruct array ($unwind)
> > - sort by id ($sort)
> > - re-construct array ($group)
>
> - sort by productId ($sort)
> - re-construct productList ($group)
> - sort by customerId ($sort)

- `$unwind` deconstruct `productList` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$productList" },
```

- `$unwind` deconstruct `productList.itemList` array

```
  { $unwind: "$productList.itemList" },
```

- `$sort` by `productList.itemList.id` ascending order

```
  { $sort: { "productList.itemList.id": 1 } },
```

- `$group` by all 3 main level of ids and re-construct `itemList` array

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        customerId: "$customerId",
        productId: "$productList.productId"
      },
      itemList: { $push: "$productList.itemList" }
    }
  },
```

- `$sort` by `productId` ascending order

```
  { $sort: { "_id.productId": 1 } },
```

- `$group` by main 2 level of ids and re-construct `productList` array

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id._id",
        customerId: "$_id.customerId"
      },
      productList: {
        $push: {
          productId: "$_id.productId",
          itemList: "$itemList"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

- `$project` to show required fields

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      customerId: "$_id.customerId",
      productList: 1
    }
  },
```

- `$sort` by `customerId` id

```
  { $sort: { customerId: 1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8xeLMZa_l0r)

Comment: I try your first post, doesn't sort correctly `productList.productId`.

Comment: @turivishal is there any way to do sorting without unwinding? I have faced a prblm tht i jave three level nested array where i need to sort

Comment: @varman i don't know but will check, and i think unwind is expensive for query, might be affect performance and speed, will ask to the community and update you.

Comment: Sure. Thank you, unwind is expensive when we use lot of data. Let me know if you get help, i will if i get.

Comment: @varman Yes, many things are expensive if you use MongoDb with millions of data.

Comment: @varman you can use [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html) to build your own operator, check sort operator [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60957218/8987128) from v4.4, or might be there is no option other than unwind

Comment: @fuat, have you solved your problem with this answer? let me know is there any issue with query.

Comment: @turivishal Thank you, i will look this