# MongoDB nested sort not working, need suggestion

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my Mongodb data...

[image: Data]

I'm using this node/mongoose script to get a particular exam sorted by the score.

```
User.find("completedExams.exam": "test-1").sort({'completedExams.score': -1}).select({'completedExams.$': 1, name: 1}).limit(5).exec(
  function(err, allScores) {
    if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
    res.json(allScores);
  });
```

But I'm getting this. it's not sorting by score

[image: Output]

Comment: sorting will not work in array field, you can to do it by aggregate().

Comment: please help me with the code, I'm new in Mongodb

Comment: please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388127/mongodb-sort-inner-array you will get the idea about it, or search for the same, Lots of questions in SO related this.

Comment: thanks for the link.. Did you checked the attached images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this with aggregation. This is plain mongo query. I hope you can translate it into nodejs. Here is the query :-

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$completedExams"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "completedExams.exam": "test-1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "completedExams.score": -1
    }
  }
])
```

And here is link to [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z4tNZpdwNGx)

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I really wanted :)