# How to sort a field inside an array in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

[mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RbSwOV9YA6z)

I want to sort the **views** from biggest to smallest inside for each category. How to sort this?

So the expected outcome should be like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "101",
    "cars": [
      {
        "carName": "CyberTruck",
        "driverId": "202",
        "views": 50
      },
      {
        "carName": "Model 3",
        "driverId": "202",
        "views": 40
      },
      {
        "carName": "Model x",
        "driverId": "202",
        "views": 30
      }
    ],
    "categoryName": "Tesla"
  },
  {
    "_id": "102",
    "cars": [
      {
        "carName": "X1",
        "driverId": "201",
        "views": 20
      }
    ],
    "categoryName": "BMW"
  }
]
```

Comment: Here is a similar post and answer: [Mongodb sort inner array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388127/mongodb-sort-inner-array) >note there are two answers, (1) Uses a MongoDB version prior to 4.4 aggregation, (2) Uses a 4.4 version aggregation with `$function` operator.

Comment: @prasad_ Thanks! I solved by your reference but how can I also project my categoryName? The categoryName was lost when using $group. https://mongoplayground.net/p/MsF_enDXaY7

Comment: I solved: https://mongoplayground.net/p/FPCU4aV9a9X