# How to sort nested objects with arrays in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If I have these two objects:

OBJECT A:

```
{
  ...,
  votes: {
    claps: [{ count: 10, }, { count: 5 }],
    hearts: [{ count: 5 }, { count: 2 }]
  }
}
```

OBJECT B:

```
{
  ...,
  votes: {
    claps: [{ count: 20 }, { count: 10 }],
    trophy: [{ count: 5 }]
  }
}
```

For instance, object A has a total of 22 votes, and object B has 35 votes.

I already have a function that, given an object, gets its total number of votes.

I also already have a `compare` function which returns `1` if greater, `0` if equals, and `-1` if less than.

But it seems to me that Mongo's `sort` doesn't support giving it a `compare` function.

How would I go about sorting these type of objects in Mongo?

Comment: What is the sorting criteria?

Comment: @D.SM sorry, if an item has a > number of votes it should be placed first

Comment: Use aggregation pipeline, $set with $size, then $sort.

Comment: In case you have MongoDB v4.4, you can use the [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html) to sort the array using an aggregation query. With earlier versions (v4.2 or less), you can try something like in this post: [Mongodb sort inner array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388127/mongodb-sort-inner-array). Also, note there are quite a few posts out on the net...