# MongoDB set of values with a limit size

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am updating a list of transactions by saving the transaction into the database list, I do not want to have duplicate entries in the list so I use `$addtoset`

this is because the request can be fired multiple times and we want to make sure that any changes are idempotent to the database. the only catch now is that we want to only store the *latest* 20 transactions

this could be done with a `$push` `$sort` `$slice` but I need to make sure duplicate entries are not available. there was a feature request to mongo back in 2015 for this to be added to the `$addtoset` feature, but they declined this due to 'sets' not being in an order...
*which is what the $sort function would have been*

I thought I could simply append an empty push update to the update object, but from what I understand, each update is potentially threaded and can lead to undesirable edits if the push/slice fires before the `$addtoset`

right now, the values are an aggregated string with the following formula
`timestamp:value` but I can easily change the structure to an object
`{ts:timestamp, value:value}`

Update:
current code, not sure if it will work as intended as each operation maybe independent

```js
          await historyDB
            .updateOne(
              { trxnId: txid },
              {
                $addToSet: {
                  history: {
                    ts: time,
                    bid: bid.value,
                    txid: trxn.txid,
                  }
                },
                $push: {
                  history: {
                    $each: [{ts:-1}],
                    $sort: { ts: 1 },
                    $slice: -10,
                  },
                },
              },
              { upsert: true },
            ).exec();
```

Comment: Please provide an example of a document structure before and after the update. Otherwise it is not obvious how your data look like.

Comment: I read it carefully, but wasn't sure if `history` is an array inside history collection. It seems unusal. You don't describe this in the text. The query treats `history` as an array, but it could have been by mistake, what could I know.

Comment: if you have used mongo, you would be familiar with the structure. the $addtoset is working as intended, we just need to limit the total number of entries so the oldest one is gone, using a read => update => set cycle is not valid as the request could be out of date and overwrite another source as we are dealing with sharding clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't work, as you are trying to update `history` multiple times, which is not allowed in simple *update document* and raises error `Updating the path 'history' would create a conflict at 'history'`.

You can however subsequently update `history` field multiple times with *aggregation pipeline*.

```
await historyDB.updateOne(
  { trxnId: txid},
  [{
    $set: {
      history: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            historyObj: {
              ts: time,
              bid: bid.value,
              txid: trxn.txid,
            },
            historySafe: { $ifNull: ["$history", []] }
          },
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $in: ["$$historyObj", "$$historySafe"] },
              then: "$history",
              else: { $concatArrays: [ "$$historySafe", ["$$historyObj"] ] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
  },
  {
    $set: {
      history: {
        $function: {
          body: function(entries) {
            entries.sort((a, b) => a.ts - b.ts);
            return entries;
          },
          args: [{ $ifNull: ["$history", []] }],
          lang: "js"
        }
      }
    },
  },
  {
    $set: {
      history: {
        $slice: [ "$history", -10 ]
      }
    }
  }],
  { upsert: true },
).exec()
```

As of MongoDB 6.0, the second `$set` stage, which provides sorting, can be replaced with `$sortArray` operator (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70475485/14967413)).