# MongoDB sort array before $slice

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I have an aggregation pipeline that returns Regions and their respective countries with Sales value. Now I want top 5 countries by sales in each region so I'm using `$slice` but it returns first 5 countries without any order. How do I sort the `Countries` array before slicing it ?
Elements of Countries array look like this:

```
{name:"USA",sales:999}
```

The project query looks like this:

```
    "$project": {
       "Region":1,
       "TotalSales":1,
       "Countries": {
         "$slice": [
           "$Countries",
           5
         ]
       }
    }
```

MongoDB v5.0

Comment: which field are you sorting on

Comment: @cmgchess sort countries by their sales..updated question with the info

Comment: can you check if below works. i also attached a playground link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming a dummy record looks like below

```js
{
    "_id": 1,
    "Region": "North America",
    "TotalSales": 200000,
    "Countries": [
      {
        "name": "USA",
        "sales": 150000
      },
      {
        "name": "Canada",
        "sales": 50000
      },
      {
        "name": "Mexico",
        "sales": 10000
      },
      {
        "name": "Greenland",
        "sales": 5000
      },
      {
        "name": "Cuba",
        "sales": 2000
      },
      {
        "name": "Bahamas",
        "sales": 1000
      },
      {
        "name": "Jamaica",
        "sales": 500
      },
      {
        "name": "Haiti",
        "sales": 200
      },
      {
        "name": "Dominican Republic",
        "sales": 100
      }
    ]
  }
```

and that you want to sort by country sales field you can use the [`$sortArray`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/) operator (version 5.2 onwards) inside `$slice` in the `$project` stage

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      Region: 1,
      TotalSales: 1,
      Countries: {
        $slice: [
          {
            $sortArray: {
              input: "$Countries",
              sortBy: {
                sales: 1
              },    
            }
          },
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yLwdr5n4m7D)

if array doesn't have fields (something like `["UK","USA",..]`) use

```js
              input: "$Countries",
              sortBy: 1 //direction of sort
```

for versions 5.1 and below `$sortArray` doesn't work and you will have to go for a `$unwind`, `$sort`, `$group`, `$push` combo. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15389094/13583510)

the query then will look like

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$Countries"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "Countries.sales": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      Countries: {
        $push: "$Countries"
      },
      Region: {
        $first: "$Region"
      },
      TotalSales: {
        $first: "$TotalSales"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      Region: 1,
      TotalSales: 1,
      Countries: {
        $slice: [
          "$Countries",
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P5JCBWmJ4DR)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response...it does work for v5.2+ but the version that I'm using is v5.0..is there any way to achieve the same functionality in v5 ?

Comment: must be possible according to docs `The 
$sortArray
 syntax and semantics are the same as the behavior in a $push operation modified by $sort.`

Comment: $sortArray was introduced for v5.2 and above..on using it in v5 it throws InvalidPipelineOperator error

Comment: yeah need to figure out the equivalent using push and sort. let me see

Comment: Does the job...thanks.