# mongodb sorting using array field

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This is my mongodb document

```
{
    "_id" : "a3s6HzG9swNB3bQ78",
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "cmt_text" : "opp",
            "vCount" : 2,

        }, 
        {
            "cmt_text" : "o2",

            "vCount" : 5,

        }, 
        {
            "cmt_text" : "o3",

            "vCount" : 3,

        }
    ],

    "question" : "test ques 3"
}
```

i want to sort the result using the `vCount` field how to achieve this

i tried the following but seems to be not working

```
Coll.findOne( {_id:this._id},{sort:{ "comments.vCount" : 1 }});

Coll.findOne( {_id:this._id},{sort:{ "comments.$.vCount" : 1 }});
```

anyone have idea about this???

**EDIT**

we are returning only one document  and i want to display that document comment array values  according to the `vCount`. my code

```
{{#each all_comments.comments}}

    <br>{{cmt_text}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

i want to display like below

```
o2
o3
opp
```

**EDIT**

this is working fine in shell

```
db.testCol.aggregate([
                    { $unwind: "$comments" },
                    { $group: { _id: { id:"$_id", vcount:"$comments.vCount"} } },
                    { $sort: { "_id.vcount":1 }}
                  ])
```

why is it not working in my meteor app it says

```
error:object has no method aggregate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aggregate` isn't currently available on the client. You can just do a `findOne`, extract the comments array, and return a sorted version to the template. For example:

```js
Template.allComments.helpers({
  comments: function() {
    var coll = Coll.findOne(this._id);
    return _.sortBy(coll.comments, function(comment) {
      return -comment.vcount;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="allComments">
  {{#each comments}}
    <br>{{cmt_text}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is correct:

```
Coll.findOne( { _id: this._id }, { sort: { 'comments.vCount' : 1 } } );
```

**No** `$` in front of `sort`.

**EDIT:**

If you want to sort the nested array, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432727/mongodb-sort-nested-array-of-objects).

Comment: it is showing error `uncaught exception: error: { "$err" : "Unsupported projection option: comments.vCount", "code" : 13097 }`

Answer (score 1):

You should learn aggregation for dealing with subdocuments, arrays and also with subdocuments in arrays. For your sort question this could work.

```
db.testCol.aggregate([
                    { $unwind: "$comments" },
                    { $group: { _id: { id:"$_id", vcount:"$comments.vCount"} } },
                    { $sort: { "_id.vcount":1 }}
                  ])
```

**EDIT:** In according to your edit you could add `$project` operator like;

```
db.testCol.aggregate([
                        { $unwind: "$comments" },
                        { $group: { _id: { id:"$_id", vcount:"$comments.vCount", text:"$comments.cmt_text"} } },
                        { $sort: { "_id.vcount":1 }},
                        { $project: { text: "$_id.text", _id:0}}
                      ])
```

Comment: Error:Object [object Object] has no method 'aggregate'  working fine in mongoshell but not in my program