# MongoDB Sorting Nested Array Fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb

I have a collection of item that has price depending on user membership (silver, gold, platinum)

```
{ 
  ..
  memberships: [
   {level: "silver", price: 100},
   {level: "gold", price: 90},
   {level: "platinum", price: 80}
  ]
}
```

when silver users browse for items, they will need to see items sorted by price using memberships price where level is silver.

How do I sort this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort nested array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432727/sort-nested-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and then [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) in aggregation pipeline. eg: [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YbWFsItSpqO)

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{ $unwind: "$memberships" },
{ $sort: { "memberships.price": 1 }},
{ $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    "memberships": { $push: "$memberships" }
  }
})
```