# How to custom sort only specific results in Spring MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible to sort only results that matches a condition in Spring Mongo?
Let us say I have this data:

| Color | Fruit | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Orange | Orange | 23 |
| Red | Apple | 4 |
| Red | Strawberry | 66 |
| Yellow | Banana | 2 |

I want to sort the list to display the Fruits with color red on Top and the remaining fruits will be sorted by amount. So the resulting table should be.

| Color | Fruit | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Apple | 4 |
| Red | Strawberry | 66 |
| Yellow | Banana | 2 |
| Orange | Orange | 23 |

So far here is what I've tried using aggregation.

```
val match1: MatchOperation = Aggregation.match(Criteria("Color").`is`("Red"))
val match2: MatchOperation = Aggregation.match(Criteria("Color").`is`("Red").not())
val sortByAmount=  sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "Amount")
val aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match1, sortByAmount, match2, sortByAmount)

val output: AggregationResults<Fruits> = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "fruits", Fruits::class.java)
```

But I'm only getting this as a result

| Color | Fruit | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Apple | 4 |
| Red | Strawberry | 66 |

Comment: You can do this custom sorting using MongoDB Aggregation [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) operator.

Comment: See the post about using the `$function`: [Sort nested array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432727/sort-nested-array-of-objects). You can convert your documents to an array, then sort using a custom JavaScript function with the `$function`, and then convert the array back to documents - the result. All in a pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this using the `$facet`; with two facets one for "red" and the other for the "not-reds".

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    facet(
        match(where("color").is("red")),
        sort(ASC, "amt"))
    .as("reds")
    .and(
        match(where("color").ne("red")),
        sort(ASC, "amt")
    ).as("others"),
    project()
       .and(arrayOf("reds").concat("others"))
       .as("result"),
    unwind("result"),
    replaceRoot("result")
);

AggregationResults<Document> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "fruits", Document.class);
results.forEach(doc -> System.out.println(doc.toJson());
```

I am using input documents as follows, for brevity: `{ color: 'red', amt: 12 }, { color: 'blue', amt: 2 }, { color: 'green', amt: 4 }, { color: 'red', amt: 3 }, { color: 'yellow', amt: 5 }`

*Another way* is by using the `$function` operator. This requires Spring Data MongoDB v3.2 and MongoDB v4.4. I didn't have a chance to actually run the code (I think it should work).

The pipeline is to be built using these four stages:

```
GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group().push("$$ROOT").as("docs");
AddFieldsOperation addFieldsOperation = Aggregation.addFields()
                                            .addFieldWithValue("docs",
                                                                ScriptOperators.Function.function(JAVASCRIPT_FUNCTION).args("docs").lang("js"))
                                            .build();
UnwindOperation unwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("docs");
ReplaceRootOperation replaceRootOperation = Aggregation.replaceRoot("docs");
```

The string JAVASCRIPT_FUNCTION (used in the `AddFieldsOperation`) has the following JavaScript function which actually sorts an array of the *fruits* documents.

```
function (a, b) {
  if (a.color == 'red' && b.color == 'red') {
      return a.amt - b.amt;
  }
  if (a.color == 'red' || b.color == 'red') {
     if (a.color == 'red') return 0;
     return 1;
  }
  return a.amt - b.amt;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was having an issue with ".and(arrayOf("reds").concat("others"))" because and only accepts a single string. So I used "andExpression("concatArrays(preDraft, others)")" instead of .and and it is now working properly.

Comment: `and(arrayOf("reds").concat("others"))` - worked fine for me. I was using Spring Data MongoDB v2.4 and MongoDB v4.2.