# How to sort alphabet first then follow by number in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to sort data by name ASC, symbols and numbers are always come first, sorting field's type is string

I want it would be in different order:

1. letters
2. symbols
3. numbers

example data as it returns now:

```
+rest day
/day
11 some
44
rest day
sport day
```

**What i want is the alphabet order come first then follow by symbols and then numbers**

Desired output

```
rest day
sport day
+rest day
/day
11 some
44
```

Comment: You can use regexFind and an aggregation pipeline, if you want to sort like this according to the first char: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexFind/

Comment: You can possibly use the Aggregation `$function` for a custom sort on the data. For example: [How to custom sort only specific results in Spring MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327889/how-to-custom-sort-only-specific-results-in-spring-mongodb/66338328#66338328). Note that the custom sorting is achieved using a JavaScript function..

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to find the way in Mongo to sort in that specific order?

I've a weird sort order requirement

```
{ name: '> 1/2 blah'},    -- 1st Special Chars
{ name: '1/4 - 1/2 blah'},  -- 2nd Numbers
{ name: 'ABC ABC Blah Blah'}, -- 3rd Alphabets
```