# Why am I only getting the result of the first operation when building FacetOperation inside a loop in Java?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I am trying to build a **FacetOperation** inside a loop in Java, but I am only getting the result of the first operation. Here's my code:

```
FacetOperation facetOperation = null;
for (int key = 0; key < 2; key++) {
    if (facetOperation == null) {
        facetOperation = facet(match(ctx -> basicQueryOriginal.getQueryObject()),
                project().and(DATA_SOURCE_ID).as("id"),
                group("id").count().as("count"),
                project("count").andExclude("_id")
        ).as("Category " + key);
    } else {
        facetOperation.and(match(ctx -> basicQueryOriginal.getQueryObject()),
                project().and(DATA_SOURCE_ID).as("id"),
                group("id").count().as("count"),
                project("count").andExclude("_id")
        ).as("Category " + key);
    }
}

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(facetOperation);
AggregationResults<Document> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "collection", Document.class);
Document facet = groupResults.getMappedResults().get(0);
facet.forEach((key, value) -> {
    countDtos.add(new CountDto(key, ((ArrayList) value).size()));
});
```

The loop is intended to create multiple FacetOperation operations, but when I run the code, I am only getting the result for only **Category 0**.

[image]

I also want to get result of **Category 1**, I am using MongoDB Java driver and Spring Data MongoDB. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong with my code?

Additionally, without loop it works as mentioned in following answer [Multiple facets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66338328/2310536). But my need is to achieve this using loop.

**Update**

Solution suggested by @valijon works for me. Now I have also created a [Text Index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/avoid-text-index-name-limit/) in collection.
I am able to add sorting on this in my basic query and it works fine using this:

```
basicQuery.fields().projectAs(MongoExpression.create("'$meta' : 'textScore'"), "score");
Document document = new Document("score", MongoExpression.create("'$meta' : 'textScore'").toDocument());
basicQuery.setSortObject(document)
```

Now when I try to use this basic query in Aggregation. I get following error:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 40218 (Location40218): 'query requires text score metadata, but it is not available' on server localhost:27017.
```

How can I make aggregation to either ignore the text index or make use of $meta?

Comment: You need to assign to `facetOperation` variable each new query criteria: `facetOperation = facetOperation.and(...)`.

Comment: Hi @Valijon I hope you are doing fine. You suggestion worked for me. Now I have to modify it to also take in account text index while performing aggregation. I searched and tried alot without any luck. I would be really thankful if you could let me know if its possible.

Comment: Hey. Could you please update your question and add some sample data and expected result?

Comment: @Valijon Thank you. I had found the solution, will add as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the change suggested by @Valijon and was able to add support for text index in aggregation pipeline.

Here is my final code which works:

```
FacetOperation facetOperation = null;
for (int key = 0; key < 2; key++) {
    if (facetOperation == null) {
        facetOperation = facet(match(ctx -> basicQueryOriginal.getQueryObject()),
                project().and(DATA_SOURCE_ID).as("id"),
                group("id").count().as("count"),
                project("count").andExclude("_id")
        ).as("Category " + key);
    } else {
        facetOperation = facetOperation.and(match(ctx -> basicQueryOriginal.getQueryObject()),
                project().and(DATA_SOURCE_ID).as("id"),
                group("id").count().as("count"),
                project("count").andExclude("_id")
        ).as("Category " + key);
    }
}
MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(
        new TextCriteria().matchingAny("[street]").caseSensitive(false)
);
AddFieldsOperation addFieldsOperation = addFields()
        .addFieldWithValue("score", new Document("$meta", "textScore")).build();

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(matchOperation, addFieldsOperation, facetOperation);
AggregationResults<Document> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "collection", Document.class);
Document facet = groupResults.getMappedResults().get(0);
facet.forEach((key, value) -> {
    countDtos.add(new CountDto(key, ((ArrayList) value).size()));
});
```